# Unable to set default browser (always goes back to IE)

Tags: windows-xp, browser

For some reason today my machine (XP SP3) will only use IE as my default browser. In chrome, when I click make chrome default, nothing happens. In firefox when I click the check now button firefox always tells me it's not the default.

I've also tried setting a default via the set program access and defaults control panel option, but this also seems to get overwritten each and every time I try it.

I am in the local administrators group and everything was fine yesterday. I also don't recall installing anything yesterday.

I'm at a bit of a loss where else to look.

Comment: Are you otherwise able to edit the registry?  Also you say you are on  the local administrators group, but is the system using domain controls?

Comment: Yes, I can edit the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is frustrating.

I rebooted my machine and now everything is fine. I have no idea what was wrong, but it's not any more.

Comment: A reboot on a Windows PC fixes more issues than any other single solution. Sometimes 2 or 3 reboots does the trick, gotta love windows.